# Conditional Chaining of http handlers in golang

Tags: http, go, httphandler, chaining

I want to conditionally add http handler based on certain condition

```golang
func ConditionalCheck(arg string) func(http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return func(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
        return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
            ctx := r.Context()
            check, ok := ctx.Value("specific").(bool);
            if check {
                SpecificCheck(arg)
            } else {
                next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
            }
        })
    }
}

func SpecificCheck(arg string) func(http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return func(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
        return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
            // something
            next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
        })
    }
}

chain := alice.New(ConditionalCheck, .........)
```

When I test, the SpecificCheck `HandlerFunc` is not getting invoked.
How do I chain this based on condition?

Comment: @mkopriva precisely that's what we are doing. `alice` - https://github.com/justinas/alice

Comment: You could do the following: https://go.dev/play/p/xKeVEuQPLF2. And you could of course keep the initial signature of `SepecificCheck` and do [this](https://go.dev/play/p/5rce3yXI5RB) as well, or [this](https://go.dev/play/p/p3bVzwzknGu).

Comment: @mkopriva can you add this as answer. Thanks for https://go.dev/play/p/5rce3yXI5RB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SepecificCheck` just returns a function that takes one handler and returns another, it does not execute any of those returned objects. If you want to execute those objects you must do so explicitly, e.g.

```golang
SepecificCheck(arg)(next).ServeHTTP(w, r)
```

The above immediately calls the middleware function returned by `SepecificCheck` and then invokes the `ServeHTTP` method on the handler returned by that middleware function.

Then the updated `ConditionalCheck` would like the following:

```golang
func ConditionalCheck(arg string) func(http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return func(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
        return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
            ctx := r.Context()
            check, ok := ctx.Value("specific").(bool)
            if check {
                SpecificCheck(arg)(next).ServeHTTP(w, r)
            } else {
                next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function SpecificCheck is returning anonymus function only, but not calling it. You have to add call of returned function, like this SpecificCheck(arg)()

For example

```
    package main
    
    import "fmt"
    
    func main() {
        test("Eugene")
    }
    
    func test(name string) func() {
        return func() {
            fmt.Println("Hello! " + name)
        }
    }
```

As you can see, output empty

But this code will work right

```
    package main
    
    import "fmt"
    
    func main() {
        test("Eugene")()
    }
    
    func test(name string) func() {
        return func() {
            fmt.Println("Hello! " + name)
        }
    }
```